# How do i make a vanity .onion address?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, configuration

I want to make a vanity .onion address for torchat i would really appreciate if someone could give me a step-by-step tutorial that is guaranteed to work for making a vanity address thank you :)

Comment: // , Good question! A lot of possible Tor users don't think of "random" or not, but in terms of "custom" or "vanity." Glad to see you're part of the process!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Scallion](https://github.com/lachesis/scallion) to generate onion addresses.

The documentation on how to compile and use it to generate addresses are in the readme at the provided link, the instructions are so big I did not want to copy it all in here.

Comment: // , Maybe just a screenshot?